# How to get rid of GoRouter initial route builder method always being called inbetween navigations

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

My `app_router.dart` looks like this

```
GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: AppRoute.todoList.name,
      redirect: (context, state) async {
        var initialRoute = await getInitialRoute();
        return initialRoute != AppRoute.todoList.name ? "/$initialRoute" : null;
      },
      builder: (context, state) => TodoListScreen(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
            path: 'add',
            name: AppRoute.todoAdd.name,
            builder: (context, state) => TodoAddScreen()),
        GoRoute(
            path: 'edit/:id',
            name: AppRoute.todoEdit.name,
            builder: (context, state) {
              final todoId = state.pathParameters['id']!;
              return TodoEditScreen(todoId: int.parse(todoId));
            })
        ]
    )
```

The problem I have is that whenever I navigate to `add` or `edit` for example, `TodoListScreen()` builds its entire widget tree again (after the add, edit widget tree has been built). I.e. it builds the TodoListScreen widget again, it does this even when I navigate into child widgets of `add` and `edit` This is causing issues for me data retention-wise.

> AppRoute is just an enum

Is this by design when using goRouter? If not can someone help me refactor this?

Thanks in advance!